# How to ALTER a view in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

PostgreSQL does not allow altering a view (i.e. adding column, changing column orders, adding criterie etc.) if it has dependent objects. This is really getting annoying since you have to write a script to:

1. Drop all the dependent objects,
2. Alter the view,
3. Recreate all the dependent objects back again.

I understand that postgreSQL developers have very reasonable concerns to prevent altering views. But do you guys have any scripts/shot-cuts to do all those manual stuff in a single run?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding new columns isn't a problem, changing datatypes or changing the order of the columns, that's where you get problems.

1. Don't change the order, it's not
   that important anyway, just change your query:

   SELECT a, b FROM view_name;

   SELECT b, a FROM view_name;
2. When you have to change a datatype
   of a column, you have to check the
   depend objects as well. These might
   have problems with this new
   datatype. Just get the definition of
   this object and recreate after the
   changes. The information_schema and
   pg_catalog help you out.
3. Make all changes within a single
   transaction.

Comment: Adding a column is a problem when view has dependent objects. Try this;


CREATE TABLE one
(
 col_a INT,
 col_b VARCHAR(2),
 col_c DATE
 );

CREATE OR REPLACE view vw_one
AS 
SELECT col_a, col_b 
  FROM one;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vw_two
AS
SELECT col_a, col_b 
  FROM vw_one;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vw_one
AS
SELECT col_a, col_b, col_c 
  FROM one;

Am I missing something?

Comment: It works fine over here, 9.0beta4. I don't have older versions at my dev machine, but it should work in 8.4 as well. What error message do you get?

Comment: They might have fixed on version 9.0. I saw couple of bug fix request in postgreSQL community. Here's the error I'm getting.
ERROR: cannot change number of columns in view
SQL state: 42P16

Comment: And what version do you have? SELECT version();

Comment: From the 8.4 release notes: Allow CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW to add columns to the end of a view (Robert Haas)

Answer (score 2):

If I place a addtional "drop view xyz; commit;" before the "create or replace view xyz as ..." statement, at least in many cases I resolve the blocking problem described above.

Comment: Thanks. I did the opposite (removed 'drop view', added 'or replace') and it worked great.